# OPTION STRICT set to off

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am working on an application with over one million lines of code.  OPTION STRICT is set to off!.

I want to set it to ON during the next work iteration.  I believe the only reason OPTION STRICT should be OFF is when converting a legacy system e.g. VB6 to .NET.  You should then set OPTION STRICT to ON ASAP.

Am I right in this thought or do developers leave OPTION STRICT to OFF permanently? Is there any guidance.  I have looked here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx, but I cannot find an answer to my specific question.

Comment: Before deciding categorically to switch the option, I would first check (test if you can) how many things get broken when you do the change, and then evaluate the following steps...

Comment: I just recently was working on a single form (similar situation to yours) and spent 3 hours fixing all the resulting compiler errors - without finishing the whole form.  I'm staying OPTION STRICT off for the time being, annoying as it is.

Comment: @psr thanks. I spent exactly three hours on this today and i am coming to the same conclusion. Did you roll back the three hours work or are you three hours closer to making your project option strict?

Comment: @w0051977 Do make sure you have adequate testing mechanisms before you attempt the change. Some changes may silently break the code because of implicit conversion assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

It is a real pity Microsoft defaults to `Option Strict Off`, although I sort of understand from their point of view.

Yes, for any professional coding you ought to use `Option Strict On`, and only turn it off in files that need to use late-binding on `Object`.

Nevertheless, once you have a large project where you want to turn `Option Strict On` you run into the problem that, in the IDE, Microsoft limits to reporting 100 errors or warnings. For recent versions they've removed that limit from the command line compiler so you can know how big your task is to fix the missing casts.

A quirk I have noticed when adding casts is that the error messages are sometimes "better" from the "simple" `Option Strict Off` automatic conversion failures than those returned by explicit casts.